# Pod install issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have Podfile that contains this lines

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'AdMob', '~> 6.5.0'
pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.2.3'
pod 'RevMobSDK'
```

when I try to run `pod install` i get this error below:

Unable to find a specification for `AdMob (= 6.5.0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AdMob is now in a different spec, maintained by Google:

```
-> Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (6.6.1)
   Monetize your mobile applications with Google ads
   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 6.6.1'
   - Homepage: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/
   - Source:   http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googlemobileadssdkios-6.6.1.zip
   - Versions: 6.6.1, 6.6.0 [master repo]
```